# how to "randomize the color "of arrayed object

Tags: modifiers, shaders, color-management

I was making the tutorial of the "easy environment design " of Ducky 3D.
I wanted to try to randomize the color of the arrayed cylinders' emission part.
by info object node and color ramp.
but I couldn't.
shall anyone helps me?[image]

I made the changes that Dear lemon said. but It didn't help me. would you please let me know if there is anything that I have not done?
[image]

thanks alot.many many thanks.
[image]

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195876/how-do-i-create-array-of-objects-of-alternating-color/195877#195877

Comment: Agreed. Since it looks like Eevee you won't be able to use random per Island output, so offseting the uvs in the array modifier seems like the next best thing :)

Comment: Please don't use answers if you didn't solve your problem, you can instead edit your question to add more information. This will help potential helpers find your question if it seems it is unanswered. In the case of cycles, you can instead of the random per object output, use a Geometry node and use its Random Per Island output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same method as provided in @lemon's answer, you can also achieve random colors with a white noise node :

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, dear Gorgious

Answer (score 4):

A possible way to do it is to use UV offset from the array modifier (as mentioned by Gorgious, random per island is not implemented for Eevee).

[image]

From that we can use UV texture coordinates:

[image]

- Get X (U from UV) value
- Multiply it (just to tune randomness)
- Get cell value to have one color per arch
- Use Voronoi texture to have randomness (easier to tune than noise texture)
- Eventually map range to tune the result
- Plug it to a colorramp containing the colors you want

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, dear Lemon