# Is there a way to paint/remove part of this texture?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

So I have these road lines that I have created with a brick texture an mapping, ive repositioned in everyway and I have gotten the perfect size for them! but I would like more space between them, is there a way I can remove ''some'' of the lines without removing them all? like an Eraser tool of sorts?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [this Robin Betts' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/195896/78972) and limit the width of the stripes with a mask
Then you can adjust gap and stripe length independently :).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115824/discussion-on-answer-by-jachym-michal-is-there-a-way-to-paint-remove-part-of-thi).